# Colored and inclined boxes

Tags: graphics, color, boxes, backgrounds

I would like to get the following colored boxes so that they are also slightly inclined. Here is a picture of what it should look like
[image]

Can someone tell me how to do this with latex? Which packages do you have to use for this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{mybox}[2]{
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    colback=#2,
    arc=2pt,
    tikz={rotate=#1,transform shape},
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0pt}{-.5pt}{1pt}{blue!90!white},
    nobeforeafter}

\begin{document}

\mybox{15}{red!40}{$f_1(x) = x^4 - 3x^2 + 1$}
\mybox{-10}{yellow!40}{$f_2(x) = x^2 - 3$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @user187803 using `tcolorbox` is probably the right way to do this, especially is you want the fuzzy shadow. For variety, here is a TikZ solution using `drop shadow`.

[image]

`\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` is unnecessary, but allows the use of fun color names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand{\colbox}[3]{\tikz{\node[fill=#1,rotate=#2,inner sep=2mm,
    drop shadow]{$#3$}}}

\begin{document}

\colbox{Salmon}{5}{f_1(x)=x^4-3x^2+1}\quad
\colbox{SkyBlue}{-5}{f_2(x)=-x^5-x^3+4x}\quad
\colbox{GreenYellow}{10}{f_3(x)=-x^8-3x^4-1}

\colbox{Dandelion}{10}{f_6(x)=-x^8-3x^4+1}\quad
\colbox{Lavender}{-10}{f_5(x)=-x^5-x^3-4x}\quad
\colbox{Thistle}{-10}{f_4(x)=-x^3-2}

\end{document}
```